# ConcurrentDictionary methods

Tags: c#

I am new to concurrent dictionaries and all their new methods involving "Try". I have coded a simple method below that retrieves roomInformation from a dictionary (roomInformation is a class) and then prints it if it exists as well as  returns true.

Have I done this right? is there a better way? please do let me know if a more robust alternative solution exist.

```
public bool TryGetRoomInformation(int roomId, out RoomInformation roomInformation)
        {
            if (!_roomInformation.ContainsKey(roomId))
            {
                roomInformation = null;
                return false;
            }

            if (_roomInformation.TryGetValue(roomId, out roomInformation))
            {
                return true;
            }

            roomInformation = null;
            return false;
        }
```

Useage:

```
RoomInformation roomInfo;
if (!RoomManager.TryGetRoomInformation(1, out roomInfo))
{
    // didnt find anything :(
    return;
}

// use roomInfo, it was found
```

Comment: This doesn't look right. Can you post the entire code? It's not possible to review this small snippet.

Comment: Have you considered using locks? Or a transactional database?

Comment: There's nothing specific to concurrent dictionaries here. `TryGetValue` is part of the `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` interface.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I noticed, you can eliminate the first if block, that condition is handled later.  If the key is invalid TryGetValue will return false and this way you only lookup the key once:

```
public bool TryGetRoomInformation(int roomId, out RoomInformation roomInformation)
{
    if (_roomInformation.TryGetValue(roomId, out roomInformation))
    {
        return true;
    }

    roomInformation = null;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked out the best way of doing this is like this...

```
public bool TryGetRoomInformation(int roomId, out RoomInformation roomInformation)
{
    return _roomInformation.TryGetValue(roomId, out roomInformation);
}
```

Comment: One difference is, you're not specifically setting roomInformation to null

Comment: Its initially set to null because no parameter is actually passed, its just declared, so roomInformation's default = null.

Comment: One caveat to that is, that in the future it would be easy to forget that and actually pass a RoomInformation object that isn't null.  Specifically forcing it to null would cover that eventuality.

Comment: Your reply makes no sense, if the method returns false the roomInformation method is never even used so it doesn't matter and adding to the _roomInformation dictionary it checks for nre

Comment: If the roomInformation already has a value and the method returns false, it will contain the old value not null.  Adding a default value to the out object is safer in the long run.

Comment: It will not contain the old value, since `out` parameter must be set by called method. This is enforced by compiler. And as with other `TryX` methods, `TryGetValue` sets `out` parameter to `default(T)` if operation failed.

Comment: @tinstaafl `TryGetValue` always assigns to its `out` parameter, that's a C# requirement for `out` parameters.  It uses `default(T)` which is `null` for nullable types when it doesn't find an entry for the key.

Comment: If it is down to one line then might as well inline it.

Comment: @Paparazzi I find inline ugly, personal preference though.

Comment: @paparazzo but now your wrapper code gets called inline, I would wrap that one too.. and thinking about it, the new wrapper too, and so on.. where does madness begin and where does it stop?